# Git: Ignore incoming changes by marking a branch as merged

Tags: git, devops

I need to know how to tell git to mark branches as merged while ignoring incoming changes. I will try and demonstrate the problem:

Create new branch "dev"
Branch dev has change 1, 2, 3.
Create branch "qa" (from dev)
Branch qa has change 4 (this change will only ever exist in qa)
Switch to branch dev
Branch dev gets changes 5, 6
Need to merge branch dev onto qa WITHOUT CONFLICTS (DevOps is doing this merge)

Normally I would just say merge qa back to dev, using "take mine" to resolve conflict.
In this case, I will NEVER want changes from qa.

What is the simplest way for me to mark the qa changes so that they are never copied to the dev branch? I am trying to build a simplified workflow for my data warehouse team to follow.

Comment: But why would you get conflicts when merging dev into QA _if it is not for the changes that are only applied on QA_? If you use _take mine_, the _non conflicting_ changes in QA will land in dev and that is something you don't want, if I understand correctly.

Comment: This sounds reversed. If you want to changes of dev in qa, you have to merge dev to qa, not the other way round (or rebase qa onto dev). If there are conflicts, you have to resolve them – either manually or by specifying the merge strategy option (e.g. `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - if two sets of changes conflict, you cannot create a state that reflects both sets of changes without performing manual conflict resolution.  Your reason for wanting to do so might be valid, but that doesn't change the fact that it can't be done.

---

"Marking a branch as merged" is easy; but it won't do what you're wanting it to do.

Your starting point looks like

```
... 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 5 -- 6 <--(dev)
                \
                 4 <--(qa)
```

Now you want to merge `dev` to `qa` without conflict.  The thing is, either the changes in `5` and `6` conflict with the changes in `4`, or they don't.  And if they do, "marking the branches as merged" won't change anything.  So you can say

```
git checkout dev
git merge -s ours qa
```

and this will create a "merge" commit that keeps the exact content from commit `6` regardless of conflicts, just as you've asked.  (Note that `-s ours` changes the *merge strategy*, which is different from `-X ours`, which passes a *merge strategy option*.  The latter is what you describe as "using 'take mine' to resolve conflict".  `-X ours` changes the conflict handling but still performs a merge of non-conflicting changes; but `-s ours` ignores "their" content altogether.)

So now you'd have

```
... 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 5 -- 6 -- M <--(dev)
               \            /
                 ---- 4 --- <--(qa)
```

where `M` has the same content as `6`.  But now `qa` still doesn't have the changes from `5` or `6`; so your DevOps go to

```
git checkout qa
git merge dev
```

The problem is, `qa` is now reachable from `dev` because of your first merge.  So by default this will fast-forward `qa` to `dev`

```
... 1 -- 2 -- 3 -- 5 -- 6 -- M <--(dev)(qa)
               \            /
                 ---- 4 ---
```

which adds the `5` and `6` changes to `qa`, *but also removes the `4` changes from `qa`*.

Even if you avoid the fast-forward, you'll get the same result with a different history.  (`fast-forward` is only used when this is true.)  To evaluate the full 3-way merge, you would recognize `4` as the merge base (it's the most recent commit reachable from both branches), `4` as "ours", and `M` as "theirs".

So you calculate "our changes"; but "ours" is the same commit as the merge base, so this is an empty patch.

That means the merge will consist entirely of applying *their changes* ("the difference from `4` to `6`") as a patch to `4`... which means you get a copy of the state at `6`.  So again, that means the `qa`-specific changes are removed by the merge.

To change this, you'd have to perform some manipulation that makes git recognize `3` as the merge base (just as it would've before you merged `qa` to `dev`)... but that means the conflict is back.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. "-s ours" is what I want (change set 4 is essentially abandoned). The complication is that I want to do this is DevOps, Visual Studio, or SourceTree, none of which make this more advanced merging easier. I will have to train my developers.